# npm install --save-dev node-sass@4.7.2

Tags: npm, sass

npm install --save-dev node-sass@4.7.2

> > 

npm WARN deprecated request@2.79.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...Va0k1IWcuoPwX8jicqISh'

Answer (score 0):

Try using a newer version of node-sass.. This version depends on a no longer supported and fully deprecated librar (request). Try just

```
npm install node-sass -D
```